# What happens to my overseas driver's license after I exchange it in the UK?

Tags: uk, driving-licenses, australian-citizens

I'm currently in the UK on a working visa. I know that after I've been here for one year, I will need to exchange my Australian driver's license for a UK one if I want to drive. I've been told that this means surrendering my Australian license card.

My question is, what actually happens to my Australian license as far as Australia (NSW) is concerned? Is it cancelled? If I return to Australia before the expiry date of my original license, do I just report it as missing to the NSW registry and pay the small fee for a replacement card, or do I have to get a completely new license?

Comment: I am not sure about UK specifically, but in most countries the 'exchanging' authority keeps your original driver's license and allows you to surrender the exchanged license and get your original back.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo in some jurisdictions (New York, at least), the licensing authority destroys the exchanged license unless you tell them you'll be wanting it back.

Comment: @phoog I take it you mean they destroy the physical card, but would they tell the issuing country they destroyed it? Because if the license was still current from Australia's point of view, I would think I'd be able to just order a replacement card. Although if I could get the original back, even better... saves me $26 and a hassle. Potentially.

Comment: @xtal I haven't looked into the communication that may or may not occur; perhaps it is governed bilaterally by the agreements that allow licenses to be exchanged.  All I know is what I've read at https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/drive-new-york-state.

Comment: @xtal, [According to this page](http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roads/licence/moving-to-nsw.html) you can always swap the UK license back for a NSW license without taking tests, and you can apply for a new NSW license without tests and without swapping a foreign license within 5 years of the expiry of the old NSW license. Given this is there a reason to care if the UK tells them about that swap or not?

Comment: @Dennis Given that, no (provided my original license expiry date gets propagated through both exchanges). It's not doing tests that I'm worried about, it's the fact that I paid up for a 10-year license and there would be at least 5 years still remaining when I plan to return to NSW. The only remaining question then would be how the NSW registry copes if you try to exchange a foreign license when you already have a current NSW license number in the system... seems straightforward, but with government systems you never quite know.

Comment: Curiously, some 20 years ago I moved from Massachusetts to Virginia - and exchanged my MA license for a VA one.  Then a couple of years later, when my MA license would be expiring, my parents received a letter about renewing - which I followed up on - and ended up with two valid licenses, MA and VA.  I know this is not UK, so I'm offering it just as a comment.